# Can you use __in to filter through foreign keys?

Tags: sql, django

I have the following query:

```
Child.objects.filter(
    foreign_key_field__in=Parent.objects.filter(param=something))
```

The view dies with:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'value of something'
```

It seems to me that the `foreign_key_field` expects an `id` of some kind, and I'm giving it an actual value. Am I doing something wrong? Is this possible?

The goal is to avoid iterating over the `child_set` of the parent to call another query-generating method in the child, which causes a query to be generated for each and every single object returned. Instead, I want to induce the ORM to grab all the matching children in one query, and iterate over them as normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is are you doing:

```
Child.objects.filter(parent__in=Parent.objects.filter(...))
```

or

```
Child.objects.filter(parent_id__in=Parent.objects.filter(...))
```

The first version will work, the second version will give you the "invalid literal for int() with base 10" error.